# Visual Studio 2012 Target Schema for Validation Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 and the target schema for validation is not working (VS shows an error at launch when I open a project saying "could not complete the action".

When I check on the validation target schema setting (in Tools->Opptions->Text Editor->HTML->Validation), it does indeed have an option selected (HTML5). However, when I try to add the "Target Schema for Validation" toolbar button, it again shows the same error when loading the project "could not complete the action".

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Related: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051587/target-schema-for-validation-missing-in-vs-2012-intellisense-how-to-resolve