# Target schema for validation - missing in VS 2012 intellisense - how to resolve?

Tags: validation, visual-studio-2012, schema, intellisense

In a MVC4, razor view, I am unable to get HTML5 intellisense.

After adding [AngularJS references to VS2012 for intellisense](http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012), I still wasn't getting the any of the AngularJS directives to appear.

I have the HTML5 schema enabled (Tools/Options/Text Editor/HTML).

I also don't see any of the HTML5 intellisense as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618298.aspx).

When I type the

> <

Intellisense is "text".

Other tags show a green line with the message "Validation ($SCHEMA$): Element 'script' is not supported.

Looks like there's a disconnect somewhere with my schemas.

I also tried added the target schema for validation to the toolbar and received the error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not complete the action.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem with VS 2013. I had been messing about with the schemas used for validation, so I reckoned that was the problem, turns out I had likely corrupted one of the files.

Find a "healthy" install of VS 2012 (maybe install on another machine?), zip & copy the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html
```

Delete the directory from the "unhealthy" VS and copy the "healthy" one into it's place. Then re-start VS.

For 2013, you may also need to do the same for the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Schemas\1033\HTML
```

Prior to this I had also done a "Devenv.exe /Setup" and "Devenv.exe /ResetSettings", but I don't think these are necessary.